# How do I change the size of UINavigationBar for different UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to change the size of `UINavigationBar` (i.e. change its height) when a certain `UIViewController` is pushed on top of the stack (I'm using a `UINavigationController`). Setting the frame on `viewWillAppear:` does the trick but its animates in a funny manner and I don't want to do that. What are my other options ?

Also, when I switch back to the other `UIViewControllers` I want to set it to default height. Thanks.

Comment: It is advisable to make your UINavigatioBar of 44 pixels. Make changes in it's height may violet Apples guidelines.

Comment: you can achieve it by use of `viewWillDidAppear` method.

Comment: There's nothing like that.